# Input and If statements

Tags: java, if-statement, input

I'm trying to create a command/console calculator program but I'm getting stuck with the if statements for the operators.

I know this isn't the easiest (or even the correct) way to create a calculator program but I'm doing it this way so I can practice user Output, Input, If statements and calculations.

I was thinking that for the operator variable it would be type char, but if I do it that way I cant get the user input. Whats wrong with the following code?

```
package calculator;
import static java.lang.System.in ;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Calculator {


 public static void main(String[] args) {

     Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

 System.out.println ("Welcome to the calculator!");
 System.out.print ("Enter a calculation: ");

 int a;
 int b;
 String Op; //Operator


 a = in.nextInt();
 b = in.nextInt();
 Op = in.next();

 if (Op == '*') { a*b ;}
 if (Op =='/') { a/b ;} 
 if (Op == '+') {a+b;} 
 if (Op == '-') {a-b;} 



}

}
```

I haven't finished it off yet (as you can see there isn't any output) but that's because I cant get the if statements to work.

The errors I'm getting are:

```
 error: not a statement
 if (Op == '-') {a-b;}
```

This is for every if statement.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Answer (score 2):

There are few things that you need to consider:

1. `Op` is string so you need to compare using `.equals("op")` or `.equalsIgnoreCase("op")` method.
2. You are getting error as `not a statement` because you need to use `;` to terminate the statement so `a-b` is not statement you need to do like I am using on following code.
3. And last you are checking with `'*'` single code uses for `char`

You can see following code with formatted language.

```
public class Calculator {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Welcome to the calculator!");

    int a;
    int b;
    String Op; //Operator
    int c = 0;

    System.out.println("Enter First Value :");
    a = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Second Value :");
    b = in.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter Operator :");
    Op = in.next();

    if (Op.equals("*")) {
        c = a * b;
    } else if (Op.equals("/")) {
        c = a / b;
    } else if (Op.equals("+")) {
        c = a + b;
    } else if (Op.equals("-")) {
        c = a - b;
    }

    System.out.println("Output is " + c);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (Op == '*') { a*b ;}
 if (Op =='/') { a/b ;} 
 if (Op == '+') {a+b;} 
 if (Op == '-') {a-b;}
```

You can't compare a `String` and a `char` via `==`. But exchanging your `Char` with a `String` will help you neither. To compare two `String` objects you have to use `string1.equals(string2)`.

See [How do I compare Strings in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) for further information on that. 



Unfortunately, in this particular case, it will unnecessary complicate your code. I suggest  using a **switch-case** statement here:

```
switch (Op) {
    case "*" :
        a *= b;
        break;

    case "/" :
        a /= b;
        break;

    case "+" :
        a += b;
        break;

    case "-" :
        a -= b;
        break;

    default:
        System.out.printf("Invalid operation entered!\n");
}
```

Comment: @sp00m indeed we can have String in switch case ( from java7)

Comment: @sp00m Did you even try this?  See [The switch statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/switch.html) for further information.

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing `String` with `char` so

change `'-'` with `"-"` ( do same for other operators as well ) and compare it as `Op.equals("-")`

and about `error: not a statement`;

assign the result to a variable like 
`result = a-b`

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare two Strings using ==. == will compare th Objects, not the content of the Strings. To compare Strings use `someString.equals(otherString);`.  Further, it's `String s = "someString";` and not  not `String s = 'someString'`.

Try this:

```
 if (Op.equals("*")) { a*b ;}
 if (Op.equals("/")) { a/b ;} 
 if (Op.equals("+")) {a+b;} 
 if (Op.equals("-")) {a-b;}
```

Answer (score -3):

You should perform string comparison this way:

```
if(op.equals("*")
```

Since, you are using the `==` operator for strings you are getting this error.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. Using `==` over `.equals()` will not result in a compiler error. `error: not a statement` is due to the calculation without storing the result to a variable (`a*b` should be `result = a*b` or something to that effect).